# How can I get C# AES encryption method to return the same results as a given java method?

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I was given following java code:

```
private static String key = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"; // Not real key

public static String Encrypt(String text)
{
    byte[] encrypted, bytekey = hexStringToByteArray(key);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(bytekey, "AES");

    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(1, sks, cipher.getParameters());
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error using AES encryption with this Java instance");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
    }
    String encryptedText = byteArrayToHexString(encrypted);
    return encryptedText;
}
```

Passing `Password123` into this returns `6836A38816248A0C7DD89400A997251A`.  I'm not looking for comments on the security of this.  I'm aware.  I didn't write it, I just need to duplicate it.

I have to create C# code that has the same functionality.  I have tried many code snippets from all over SO and other web sites.  None of them produce the same output when given a specific input.

I added some debug statements to the java code to get the following information about the algorithm:

```
sks.getAlgorithm(): AES (duh)
sks.getFormat(): RAW
cipher.getAlgorithm(): AES (again, duh)
cipher.getBlockSize(): 16
cipher.getParameters(): null
cipher.getIV(): null (I think this might be my primary issue)
```

Here is one of the C# methods I found that looked promising:

```
private const string key = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"; // Not real key
private static byte[] encryptionKey= new byte[16];

static void SetupKey()
{
    var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, encryptionKey, Math.Min(encryptionKey.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
}

public static String Encrypt3(String secret)
{
    SetupKey();

    byte[] inputBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (AesManaged cryptor = new AesManaged())
        {
            cryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            cryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            cryptor.KeySize = 128;
            cryptor.BlockSize = 128;

            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptor.CreateEncryptor(encryptionKey, null), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
            }
            byte[] encryptedContent = ms.ToArray();
            byte[] result = new byte[encryptedContent.Length];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedContent, 0, result, 0, encryptedContent.Length);

            return ByteArrayToHexString(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run this code, I get a different result, even though I'm passing null into the Initialization Vector(IV) parameter of `cryptor.CreateEncryptor()`.  Is the `AesManaged` object using an internal IV even though I told it to use null?  If I try to set the IV to null, I get an error.

What do I need to do to get the C# code to consistently return the same result as the java code?

NOTE: *Both methods use HexStringToByteArray and ByteArrayToHexString. The original author of the java code, for some reason, wrote his own byte/hex converters.  I recreated them in C#, but they work just like the build in functions.*

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? You can't have null for the IV, so that probably tells it to use a random IV. You should probably specify an IV of all zeroes if you don't care about the value. You also need to make sure both are using the same encryption mode i.e., ECB, CBC, OBC, etc. What does the documentation say it means when the cipher.getParameters() is null?

Comment: In the C# code the key must be hex decoded and as mode ECB must be applied to correspond functionally to the Java code.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you.  The suggestion to make the IV all zeroes has, at least, produced consistency.  The java docs as oracle.com don't say anything about what it means if the getParameters is null, only that it will use defaults if it can.  That's why I checked getIV().  Which also returned null.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you!  That was the other thing I was missing.  I now have consistent, matching data.

Comment: CBC + zero vector and ECB are equivalent only for a single block (= 16 bytes for AES) ciphertext (compare both [flowcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC))), not for larger ciphertexts. The robust way is to use ECB in the C# code for compatibility with the Java code.

Comment: @Topaco That's good info.  I wondered why it didn't seem to matter which I chose.  My text isn't long enough to cause issues.  I don't think it will cause problems in my situation, but to be safe I will switch to ECB.